# Initializing a 2D std::array using multiple std::arrays

Tags: c++

I am attempting to initialize a 2D std::array using arrays in C++:

```
const array<bool, 7> LEDZERO = { 1,1,1,0,1,1,1 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDONE[] = { 0,0,1,0,0,1,0 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDTWO[] = { 1,0,1,1,1,0,1 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDTHREE[] = { 1,0,1,1,0,1,1 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDFOUR[] = { 0,1,1,1,0,1,0 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDFIVE[] = { 1,1,0,1,0,1,1 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDSIX[] = { 1,1,0,1,1,1,1 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDSEVEN[] = { 1,0,1,0,0,1,0 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDEIGHT[] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
const array<bool, 7> LEDNINE[] = { 1,1,1,1,0,1,0 };
const array<array<bool, 7>, 10> LEDS = { { {LEDZERO}, {LEDONE}, {LEDTWO},     
{LEDTHREE}, {LEDFOUR}, {LEDFIVE}, {LEDSIX}, {LEDSEVEN}, {LEDEIGHT}, 
{LEDNINE} } };
```

Only the first LEDZERO seems to be set to LEDS[0] correctly, LEDS[1-9] are wrong.

Comment: `const array<bool, 7> LEDONE[] = { 0,0,1,0,0,1,0 };`  -- See anything wrong with using `[]`?  The strange thing is that you didn't make the mistake with `LEDZERO`.

Comment: Oh I see, I had been trying to work with c-style arrays for a few hours and switched over to std::array. After some sleep I can see how obvious my mistake was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spurious `[]` after most `LED` variables.  This will create a C-style array of `std::array` (probably not what you want).

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDZERO = {{ 1,1,1,0,1,1,1 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDONE = {{ 0,0,1,0,0,1,0 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDTWO = {{ 1,0,1,1,1,0,1 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDTHREE = {{ 1,0,1,1,0,1,1 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDFOUR = {{ 0,1,1,1,0,1,0 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDFIVE = {{ 1,1,0,1,0,1,1 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDSIX = {{ 1,1,0,1,1,1,1 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDSEVEN = {{ 1,0,1,0,0,1,0 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDEIGHT = {{ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }};
    const std::array<bool, 7> LEDNINE = {{ 1,1,1,1,0,1,0 }};
    const std::array<std::array<bool, 7>, 10> LEDS = {{
            {LEDZERO},
            {LEDONE},
            {LEDTWO},     
            {LEDTHREE},
            {LEDFOUR},
            {LEDFIVE},
            {LEDSIX},
            {LEDSEVEN},
            {LEDEIGHT}, 
            {LEDNINE}
        }};
}
```

If you do not need `LEDZERO` through `LEDNINE`, you could write it more compact.

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    const std::array<std::array<bool, 7>, 10> LEDS = {{
            {{ 1,1,1,0,1,1,1 }},
            {{ 0,0,1,0,0,1,0 }},
            {{ 1,0,1,1,1,0,1 }},
            {{ 1,0,1,1,0,1,1 }},
            {{ 0,1,1,1,0,1,0 }},
            {{ 1,1,0,1,0,1,1 }},
            {{ 1,1,0,1,1,1,1 }},
            {{ 1,0,1,0,0,1,0 }},
            {{ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }},
            {{ 1,1,1,1,0,1,0 }}
        }};
}
```